# CSS Align button at bottom of div

Tags: html, css

So I have three divs and inside them divs are a title, description and button.

I simply want to have all the divs the same size as the highest div, but each button inside the divs should be at the bottom of each div.

So the title and description should be at the top and the button should be at the bottom.

Here is my example:

```css
.coverage-boxes { 
display: table;
height: auto;
 
}

.coverage-box { 
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width: 25%; 
padding: 15px; 
border: 2px solid #f0eaff; 
border-radius: 4px; 
text-align: left; 
vertical-align: top; 
}

.car-cover-option-button { 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
background: #ffb100; 
color: #fff; 
font-size: 0.9em; 
padding: 7px;
text-align: center; 
border-radius: 4px; 
cursor:pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="coverage-boxes">
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that.

Then apply `margin-top:auto` to your button.

```css
.coverage-boxes { 
display: flex;
height: auto;
 
}

.coverage-box { 
position:relative;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
width: 25%; 
padding: 15px; 
border: 2px solid #f0eaff; 
border-radius: 4px; 
text-align: left; 
vertical-align: top; 
}

.car-cover-option-button { 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
background: #ffb100; 
color: #fff; 
font-size: 0.9em; 
padding: 7px;
text-align: center; 
border-radius: 4px; 
cursor:pointer; 
margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="coverage-boxes">
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `display flex`, both to make the boxes stretch with `align-items` and then make `.coverage-box-table` take up all the empty space with `flex`.

You should learn flex, as doing a layout with tables is something that was done 20 years ago on the web.

```css
.coverage-boxes { 
  display: flex;          /* NEW */
  height: auto;
  align-items: stretch;   /* NEW */
}

.coverage-box { 
  position:relative;
  display:flex;           /* NEW */
  flex-direction: column; /* NEW */
  width: 25%; 
  padding: 15px; 
  border: 2px solid #f0eaff; 
  border-radius: 4px; 
  text-align: left; 
  vertical-align: top; 
}

.coverage-box-table {     /* NEW */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.car-cover-option-button { 
  display: block; 
  width: 100%; 
  background: #ffb100; 
  color: #fff; 
  font-size: 0.9em; 
  padding: 7px;
  text-align: center; 
  border-radius: 4px; 
  cursor:pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="coverage-boxes">
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
  <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
  <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the inner content of the `coverage-box` into two other divs. By doing so you can control each div separetly. And add some [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to it.

Here is my approach. I just added to extra classes to each div of the main container:

```
.top-content {
 flex: 1;
}

.bottom-content {
  bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
}
```

Check the following snippet:

```css
.coverage-boxes { 
display: table;
height: auto;
display: flex;
 
}

.coverage-box { 
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width: 25%; 
padding: 15px; 
border: 2px solid #f0eaff; 
border-radius: 4px; 
text-align: left; 
vertical-align: top; 
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.top-content {
 flex: 1;
}

.bottom-content {
  bottom: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.car-cover-option-button { 
display: block; 
width: 100%; 
background: #ffb100; 
color: #fff; 
font-size: 0.9em; 
padding: 7px;
text-align: center; 
border-radius: 4px; 
cursor:pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="coverage-boxes">
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
    <div class="top-content">
      <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
      <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
    </div>
    <div class=bottom-content>
    <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
    <div class="top-content">
      <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
      <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
    </div>
    <div class=bottom-content>
      <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="coverage-box">
  <div class="top-content">
    <div class="coverage-box-title">title</div>
    <div class="coverage-box-table">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </div>
    </div>
    <div class=bottom-content>
      <div id="car-get-basic-button" class="car-cover-option-button">My button</div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: No idea, I'm asking myself the same thing about my answer. It would be nice if someone had left a comment and given a reason – more useful for me, and more useful for the OP who needs to decide which answer is the best.

Comment: Yes, It seems like a really bad way to use the downvote option. I really happy to edit or delete my answer if something is wrong. I can even learn usefull things as well but since we have no way to found it who downvoted and there is no way to flag an unfair downvote all we can do is wonder.